# Determining reasoning behind syntax decisions in programming languages

Tags: discussion

I would like to know where to discuss the reasons behind they way things are structured in a programming language, even though my implementation works. As an example, I would like to ask the following question but am not clear on where this should be posted:

> In Vim, the regular expression syntax used in command mode for find-and-replace behaves such that only some of the special characters have to be escaped, whereas others do not. Specifically, round brackets which can be used to create capture groups actually have to be escaped in order for the parser to interpret them as a capturing group. If they are not escaped, they are treated as literal characters. The same goes for the `+` symbol to denote more than one of a particular character.
>
> This seems to be backwards compared with the way other special characters are treated (e.g., `*^$.`) because in their case, they must be escaped with a backslash to turn them into literal characters.
>
> This behaviour is not the same as in Python for example, where `(`, `)`, and `+` are treated as special characters unless escaped with a backslash. I would like to understand the reasoning behind this.

Comment: As it stands, the question is probably too broad, and opinion based, for the Main site. It may be appropriate on some other SE site, but I'm not sure where it would work. Also, I think questions such as "which SE site should I ask this?" are meant to be asked on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Pretty opinionated, if you ask me.

Your question boils down to, "Why is regex in language/utility X implemented in *this* way, but in language/utility Y it isn't?"  There's no concrete answer as to why, and languages and utilities are always evolving and changing as to further the rift between any sensible point of "fact" that could describe why a decision was made.  I say this because it could be the case that these approaches could get unified one day, because someone using Vim *really* likes the way that regexes are done in Python and decides to add that as an option.

Short of asking the actual designers, there's no way to get an answer.  And the objective of most questions on Stack Overflow shouldn't be to seek the expertise of the language implementer or chief designer of a language or service, since that means your relatively average but highly competent technical folk can't take a stab at it.

Additionally, how useful is the answer?  Is it materially relevant?  Does it matter at the end of the day if they're done in two different ways because they're two different things?  Case in point:  [Lua arrays are customarily 1-index based](https://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html) whereas other sensible languages use 0-index based arrays.  Does it matter why they did something different?  No; the only thing that matters is that it is different and you have to do something different.

Comment: "*Short of asking the actual designers, there's no way to get an answer.*" and even asking them might not lead to a great answer. Q: "Why did you do X this way?" A: "No special reason. Just happened to be the easiest thing at the time and it stuck". Sure, maybe there is a deeper reason but a lot of times a design decision is just a tradeoff. Or legacy behaviour. Or Dave did it before he left and nobody can be bothered to to touch his code. Or nobody thought of another way to do it. Etc.

Comment: Poor Dave. Their code isn't even that bad.

Comment: In this case it is legacy behavior, by the way. Vim is based on Vi, and Vi uses [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

Comment: @oguzismail I owe you one for answering the question you knew I wanted to figure out.